# How can i get value or check the role from Identity Server 4 to my MVC client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have an MVC Client (ASP.NET core) that interacts with Identity Server 4 (with Identity ASP.NET "installed") for all the functions of Login, Registration etc ..., without API.

In the Client I need to check the role of the logged in user and I don't know how to do it.
I tried the solution `User.IsInRole("Administrator")` but it doesn't read me the role, as well as `[Authorize(Role="Administrator")]`.
When I log in with a user who has a role, this is actually displayed between the claims of the diagnostic page (in the image).
[image: Diagnostics Page after Login]

But the strange thing is that when I go to analyze, in the debug phase, the array of User.Claims Claims, "role" is not there or maybe I can't find it (being a beginner with Identity and Identity Server).

So how can I go about getting the role from the MVC Client?
I was thinking of creating Policy with the value of that "role", if `User.IsInRole("Administrator")` or `[Authorize (Role = "Administrator")]` cannot be used, but the problem is always that I can't get the role.

I leave you the Startup files of the client and Identity Server as well as the Config.cs of the latter so that you can analyze them better. There may be some unnecessary lines of code but it's all in development, so forgive me.

**Startup.cs** of Client

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true);
            Configuration = builder.Build();
            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
            })
                .AddCookie("Cookies")
                .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001";

                    
                    options.SignInScheme = "Cookies";
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;

                    options.ClientId = "mvc";
                    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
                    options.ResponseType = "code";

                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                   
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options => {

                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));

            });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(55);
                
            });
            
            string connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

            services.AddDbContext<SushiWebDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connString));
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        }

        
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                
                app.UseHsts();
            }
           
            
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();                    

            });

        }
    }
```

**Startup.cs** of Identity Server

```
public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Environment = environment;
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();            

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()                
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()                
                .AddDefaultUI()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;

            services.AddTransient<IProfileService, UserProfile>();

            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                    })
                    .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                    {
                        options.ConfigureDbContext = b => b.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                            sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));
                    })
                    .AddProfileService<UserProfile>();


            
            builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddGoogle(options =>
                {
                    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                    
                    options.ClientId = "copy client ID from Google here";
                    options.ClientSecret = "copy client secret from Google here";
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {


            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
            
        } 
}
```

**Config.cs** of Identity Server

```
 public static class Config
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
            new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
                
            };


        public static IEnumerable<ApiScope> ApiScopes =>
            new List<ApiScope>
            {
               
            };

        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
            new List<Client>
            {
                
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "mvc",
                    ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    
                    // where to redirect to after login
                    RedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" },

                    // where to redirect to after logout
                    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://localhost:5002/signout-callback-oidc" },

                    AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
                    }
                }
            };
    }
```

Perhaps the solution is easier than expected, forgive me for this. Thank you so much!

Comment: Roles is in Framework.  See step three : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-cs?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 2):

To get roles from IdentityServer in MVC you need to change your `Config.cs` in IdentityServer project and also change Startup.cs in MVC project as follow:

Add in Startup.cs of MVC Client

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    ...

    options.Scope.Add("roles");
    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");
    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
}
```

If we use `MapUniqueJsonKey` then all the roles will store like this:

```
...
[8] [Claim]:{role: ["Admin","User"]}
...
```

In this case, `User.IsInRole("Admin");` always return false so I prefer to get all roles like:

```
...
[8] [Claim]:{role: "Admin"}
[9] [Claim]:{role: "User"}
...
```

Add in Config.cs in IdentityServer

```
public static class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> IdentityResources =>
        new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
            new IdentityResources.Profile(),
            new IdentityResource("roles", "Your role(s)", new List<string>() { "role" })
        };
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ...

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "roles"
                }
            }
        };
```

Change `ConfigurationStore` from SQL to Config.cs:
In IdentityServer Startup.cs

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
    options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
    options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true;
    options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
    options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
    options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
    {
        CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromHours(10),
        CookieSlidingExpiration = true
    };
})
    .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
    .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
    .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
```

You can use the database instead of the `Config.cs`, but I do not prefer it because it adds a lot of tables to the database, and I prefer to use the configuration file for a small number of settings.

Comment: this solution work with identity server but don't work with identity. I'm using identity default UI for all operations, as Register New User etc... . I tried to change in your solution the LoginUrl in '/Identity/Account/Login and i don't see the role in user's claims.

Comment: In this [repository](https://github.com/mahmood-ghaem/IdentityServer-SampleWebApp) you can find the full solution that works with ASP.NET Core Identity as well.

Comment: For login and log out I'm using `AccountController.cs` prepared by `IdentityServer`, for other features using ASP.NET Core Identity.

Comment: @Andrelan I edited my answer, maybe it covers your question now.